# Should i use an abstract class or an interface for my doctrine model?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity

In Doctrine, assuming I want to implement different types of vehicles. Maybe a car, a plane, a bicycle and so on ... all these vehicles have many different properties but also very common things like they are all made of a material.

So if i want to get this material ... should i implement a abstract class `Vehicle` with a property `material` and implement getter/setter or should i define a interface `IVehicle` and define the getter/setter in there to be sure there is really a method for getting and setting the material? Or should i even use both in combination?

It feels "professional" using the interface ... but it feels wrong to define getter/setters in interfaces, so my personal feeling is:

Don't use an interface, just use the abstract class.

But is the abstract class approach protected against misuse? For example on another place i definitely expect a `Material` type returning from the `getMaterial` function ... is the abstract class approach also save for not returning complete unexpected things (like the interface does)?

So if i extend this vehicle for another concrete class, a developer should not be able to return unexpected things, but should also be able to change the logic in the particular method if needed.

Comment: I would personnaly do both because Interface is a very good place to have a strong code documentation (such as why you need your abstract class) without screwing up with Doctrine comments. If your AbstractVehicle implements `VehicleInterface`, then you can type your code when expecting a Vehicle (which in my opinion is a good practice). After making your Interface, why would you copy/paste your code on each class ? To summerize, I would do both Interface AND Abstract class

Comment: This question is off-topic for SO as it is opinionated, however, it might do better here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: Using Interfaces would give you an opportunity to use multiple inheritances.

Comment: i posted that in the other community https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/375461/should-i-use-an-abstract-class-or-an-interface-for-my-doctrine-model ... thanks

Comment: Create a MaterialInterface to flag your code that the object has material.  Then create a MaterialTrait to implement your getMaterial method.  This saves you from needing an abstract base class while at the same time it reduces repetitive code.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

You can write an abstract class with methods that return null (or some other predetermined value) that would require you to implement them in every derived class.

This approach would still require you to write some boilerplate code to check against your conditions in every class.

I would personally go with an interface here as the nature of your classes seem to be quite diverse and can only be partially generalized to a single abstract class. However, I don't see anything wrong with going the abstract class way either. In this case, the devil is in the details.

Comment: You can just make those functions `abstract` and then you have to define them in every child class instead of returning `null` or something else